# referencing a field in a node in hook_node_api

Tags: hooks, nodes

I am using drupal 6. I have a simple question:

Here's a snippet of code from my hook_node_api function:
...

```
case 'presave':
    {
        if($node->type == 'example')
        {
            if($node->content['field_alert']['#value'] == TRUE)
            {
                //do something
                drupal_set_message('Your update will be emailed out.');
            }
        }
    }
   break;
```

I want to reference the value of a field named field_alert inside of a node type "example" but I'm doing it properly since its not working. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves it should be something like this:

```
if (!empty($node->field_alert[0]['value'])) {
  //do something
  drupal_set_message('Your update will be emailed out.');
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do it. But its weird, I just tried putting a drupal_set_message right after my first if as well, and then tried modifying the content type and saving it, but I got nothing. Why am I not breaking past the first if?

Comment: Have you cleared Drupal's caches since writing the `hook_nodeapi` function?

Comment: Oh and make sure you've called it `MYMODULE_nodeapi` not `MYMODULE_node_api` like you've said in your question ;)

Comment: I just cleared the cache and still nothing. I did write it as nodeapi, above was just a typo.

Comment: a quick drupal_set_message of a print_r($node->field_alert,true) might also help track down what you need your if to check against as well...

Comment: @user1015214 Put a `drupal_set_message` at the start of the function to make sure it's being run, then one inside the `switch` statement to make sure it's being called for the `presave` op (if it's not then you might have got the function signature wrong), then double check the name of your content type. If it's got spaces in it remember it will be `content_type` not `content-type` or anything else

Comment: Perfect, I did misspell the function name, thanks. Now it works fine.